# Laying plywood over floorboards for a vinyl floor

Tags: bathroom, plywood, vinyl-flooring, vinyl

I'm installing a vinyl floor in my bathroom (replacing carpet). There is currently no underlay, so my plan is to screw down 3mm plywood sheets directly onto the boards, I can then use adhesive spray to smoothly fix the vinyl on to these sheets.

Should I leave any kind of gap to allow for expansion? Is this the best method to achieve a level vinyl floor? My biggest concern is the gap between floor and wall (tiled), and how to stop any sort of curling or spaces opening up (essentially basic waterproofing)

Advice really appreciated on this!

Answer (score 1):

Underlayment for vinyl flooring isn't screwed down, as this would require that every screw be skimmed with patch material to create a flat surface. Ordinarily, narrow-crown (1/4") staples are used to prevent the need for skimming. Underlayment must be fastened on a 6-8" grid to prevent movement.

No expansion gaps should be left. In fact, any gaps that aren't tight must be skimmed to fill and smooth them. Vinyl flooring does not span gaps without showing them through.

Normally vinyl is installed, then base trim or base shoe is installed over the edges. It's caulked against the bathtub. Rarely have I sought to "waterproof" the perimeter of a room's floor. If you have that much water sloshing around on the floor, a lifestyle change is probably in order.